# Is it possible to add a hyperlink to a facebook post?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I would like to add a hyperlink to my Facebook posts and would like to know whether or not it is possible.  Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Just type or paste a link to the page you're trying to link to within your message. Facebook will automatically make it a hyperlink when you send/post the message.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type your hyperlink on whats on your mind. like- go to google.com . Here google.com will be detect as hyperlink automatically.
Hope this helps